# Exif_read_data error in foreach

Tags: php, loops, foreach, exif

I use exif_read_data to read exif in some files (names in array).

```
$tmpuploadfolder = 'upload';
foreach ($imagefile_name_array as $value) {
    $all_exif_data = exif_read_data(JPATH_BASE.DS.$tmpuploadfolder.DS.$value,'EXIF');
    $image_camera   = $all_exif_data['Model'];
    $image_focal_l  = eval('return '.$all_exif_data['FocalLength'].';');
    $image_iso      = $all_exif_data['ISOSpeedRatings'];
    $image_lens     = $all_exif_data['UndefinedTag:0xA434'];
    $image_aperture = $all_exif_data['COMPUTED']['ApertureFNumber'];
    $shutterspeed_apex_v = eval('return '.$all_exif_data['ShutterSpeedValue'].';');
}
```

First loop it all good, all the info writes to variables. 
But the second loop (and other) the $all_exif_data array is empty.

Comment: Are you sure that all the images have EXIF data?  You should probably check `if($all_exif_data === FALSE)` after you set it.

Comment: Also what are you doing with `eval`?  That code is extremely insecure as someone could execute arbitrary code by embedding it into the images EXIF data.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. If I try to get exif data with each of them (one of this images instead array of images), it give me all data.

Comment: I need eval to calculate data and give user "correct" view of focal length and shutter speed

Comment: what is the output of `print_r($imagefile_name_array)`

Comment: Array ( [0] => 20170116_113159_DSC03985_DP.JPG [1] => 20170116_105859_A0010947_AM_1.jpg [2] => 20170113_173025_yel.png )

Comment: You dont need `eval` here. Because you dont calc anything here. Better do `intval($all_exif_data['ShutterSpeedValue'])` or `floatval($all_exif_data['ShutterSpeedValue'])`.

Comment: `.png` wont work with `exif_read_data()` because *exif_read_data  reads the EXIF headers from JPEG or TIFF*

Comment: And sometimes images have *no header* so exif_read_data() returns false.

Comment: JustOnUnderMillions, thnx, correct it (about eval)

Comment: JustOnUnderMillions, i try with only JPG. And when i try this files separately, the data wrote to variables.

Comment: JustOnUnderMillions, in atom debugger i see, that error appear only for second and more loop. I see red line on this func, but I can't see the text of error.

Comment: It was whitespace in beginning of image address. =(